# Proving two functions intersect, is this reasoning correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Original Question: Given $$ y= \frac{9x(x+2)}{(3x-1)^2} $$ find the range of y and sketch the curve. Explain why $$f(x)=\frac{9x(x+2)}{(3x-1)^2} + \cos(x) $$ has an infinite number of solutions, all of which are negative.

I am asked to explain why the following function always produces outputs when x is negative.(why the solution is negative)  I've given my reasoning a lot of thought but im not sure whether or not it is correct.

$$f(x)=\frac{9x(x+2)}{(3x-1)^2} + \cos(x) $$

first i split the two functions on seperate sides and plotted each side individually. On the right side they never intersect due to the nature of the curve while Y=1 is an asymptote so part of the curve infinitely approaches that values but never actually reaches it. My reasoning is that since cos(x) even if on the R.H.S. becomes -cos(x) will always give an output between -1 and 1, since part of the curve is infinitely appraching 1 it will always intersect. is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. "Produces outputs" is not clear. Are you asking whether $f(x) = 0$ has solutions when $x$ is negative? If you can quote the question exactly as it was asked that may help. Please do that by editing your question, not in comments.

Comment: Instead of "Explain why $f(x)=\frac{9x(x+2)}{(3x-1)^2} + \cos(x)$ has an infinite number of solutions...", did you mean "Explain why $\frac{9x(x+2)}{(3x-1)^2} + \cos(x)=0$ has an infinite number of solutions..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range is $\left[-\dfrac{9}{7},+\infty\right)$

Indeed if you solve for $x$ you get

$x=\dfrac{y+3\pm\sqrt{7 y+9}}{3 (y-1)}$

which exists only if $7y+9\ge 0\to y\ge -\dfrac{9}{7}$

Furthermore the horizontal asymptote $y=1$ is such that $y<1$ when $x<\dfrac{1}{24}$

$\dfrac{9 x (x+2)}{(3 x-1)^2}<1\to 9x^2+18x<9x^2-6x+1 \to 24x<1\to x<\dfrac{1}{24}$

which means that you are right. (I just added the technical details)

The function $-\cos x$ intersects the given function infinite times for negative values of $x$

You can see it in the picture below

Hope this can be useful

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even consider the range before